# Has many association on user-specific post tagging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-many-through, polymorphic-associations, tagging

I’m fairly new to Rails, and many-to-many relationships is a bit over my head. In my app, a `User` has many and can see others' `Posts`. They can categorise the posts *for themselves* by adding a `Tag`— just one per post. Other users can tag the same post with a different tag and that shows up just for them.

How can I make this relationship in Rails?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :tags

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :tag, :through => :user # correct?

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   has_many :posts
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write it in this way

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags
  has_many :posts, through: :tags

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
```

So each Post will have many Tags, but only 1 for each User. Btw, you can add 1 more model to store Tags and Users tagging separately

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_tags
  has_many :tags, through: :user_tags
  has_many :posts, through: :user_tags

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_tags

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_tags

class UserTags < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :tag
  belongs_to :post
```

Comment: What’s the advantage of the user_tags model?

Comment: Keep Tags unique. For example, if user1 and user2 tagged post1 by tag "ruby", in first case it will be 2 Tags "ruby" with different users to belnongs. In second case you may have 1 Tag "ruby"

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, I think you want it this way:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :tags

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :tags, :through => :user

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   has_many :posts
```

Notice, that a **Post has_many Tags**.

If you are concerned about:

> Other users can tag the same post with a different tag and that shows
>   up just for them

That is just fine. You will be able to do so, because a Tag associated with a Post **belongs_to** a User, so you can always do something like...

```
@post.tags.each do |tag|
  if tag.user == current_user
   # show tag.
  end
end
```